# How to run a bash command every time I open a file from nautilus?

Tags: bash, nautilus

Suppose I have a certain file type that every time I double click on from Nautilus I want a to run a python command on this file, how can I do this?

For example let's say I have a file called `test_file.my_extension` and a python file called `something.py` that does something on my file. I want to be able to click on `test_file.my_extension` from Nautilus and make a bash session to open and run `python something.py test_file.my_extension`. Is it possible to do such a thing?

Comment: What do you mean by simply add python at the beginning? I want the command to run automatically when I double click a file from Nautilus (If I was already on a terminal with the file name than yes, I could've just added the command at the beginning).

Comment: Would a nautilus action in the right menu fit?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/353610/add-a-new-nautilus-context-menu-action-without-using-nautilus-actions or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91876/is-it-possible-to-add-an-item-to-the-nautilus-right-click-menu-in-centos